# How to add 'style="width:100px"' in Global Custom Text field in a view?

Tags: views, security, input-formats

It seems that the **Global Custom Text** field in a view delete part of my text.

I write this:

```
<div class="my-class" style="width:100px">Hello</div>
```

but get this:

```
<div class="my-class">Hello</div>
```

The text removed is this

```
style="width:100px"
```

I need to be able to include it.

The value of the 'width' is provided by a token ([field_width]), that's why I need to add it here. It is dynamic value.

**Update:** I just see that this is a security measure, then how can I make View accept this using a function?

Comment: try `css` please

Comment: @NikhilM how?, it is dynamic value entered in the node field Width which is added with a token replacement.

Comment: I spent like 20 mins giving you a perfectly good detailed step by step answer, but I guess you were too lazy to try it. Now my answer is gone!

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/853880#comment-5652114

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fun and a little naughty solution to this:

1.) Instead of style, set the token as value="[token]" - make sure your token is only a number, no alphabetic characters like px etc.

--- Value is set and DIV is spat out ---

```
<div class="my-div" value="100"></div>
```

2.) Use jQuery to get the value of value="" - define it and use it when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var div_width = $('.my-div').val();
$('.my-div').width(div_width);
});
```

The width will now be appended to the div via inline-style using jQuery. Not optimal, not recommended but it should work.

More on adding custom jQuery to your Drupal installation: https://www.drupal.org/node/171213